# How to retrieve a public key from travis-ci.com (private build)?

Tags: travis-ci

I need to get the public key of a repository I build on travis-ci.com (private build) not travis-ci.org (public/free builds).

When I want to do that with a public repository I do it like this via the API:

```
curl https://api.travis-ci.org/repos/jonaskello/tslint-immutable/key
```

But this diesn't work for private repositories. Do I need to sign in? How can I do that with CURL? (without installing the whole ruby environment and the travis gem)